# What are red spots at 353 channel of Cosmic Background Radiation?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

As shown on http://thecmb.org/ the 353 channel of Cosmic Background Radiation has red spots that are opposite to each other and NOT at right degrees angle to our galaxy plane (instead they are at around 78 degrees). What are they? Why they are not at right angle?

Here are the pictures of them:

[image: one]
[image: two]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on here is you're seeing gas and dust emission from the extended structure of the Milky Way galaxy. Compare the longer wavelength (lower frequency) channels to the $353\operatorname{GHz}$ one. Also, have a look at [IPAC's version](https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/applications/DUST/) of the [Schlegel et al. (1998)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/bib_query?arXiv:astro-ph/9710327) map of the dust in the Milky Way. The primary places where the dust extends out of the galactic plane appear to be near the Galactic center, and the extended part of the [Orion molecular cloud complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_Molecular_Cloud_Complex).

In other words, it just comes down to the chance of where we are in the galaxy compared to regions of more dense gas and dust. This is, of course, one of the foregrounds they need to remove to produce maps of the CMB, and those red spots are regions where we can see out of the Galaxy without looking through a lot of local gas and dust.

For what it's worth, I believe that the point sources in the longer wavelength channels are [synchrotron emission](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/objects/snrs/snrstext.html) from various types of supernova remnants and/or black-holes.

Comment: btw. At first I thought it's some kind of echo from black hole merger our universe was created from, but dust makes more sense